# How can I rotate a matrix?

Tags: math, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I got the orange rectangle below from the black points and their coordinates, I'd like to straighten up that rectangle just like the green one, is there an equation for this? (I always want the long side to be at the bottom)

[image]

Comment: Look for "rotation matrix"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Math Overflow site.

Comment: @tim you mean [math.se]. Math Overflow is for research-level questions.

Comment: You don't need to rotate. Just calculate the side lengths, fix one point and reconstruct the axis-aligned rectangle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a simple 2D rotation:

```
P' = T*P
```

where

```
    | cos(theta)   -sin(theta) |
T = |                          |
    | sin(theta)    cos(theta) |
```

The signs I chose assume positive theta (in radians, of course) means a counterclockwise rotation using the right hand rule with the z-axis pointing out of the page.  A clockwise rotation, as shown in your diagram, would be the transpose of the matrix: switch the signs of the off-diagonal sine terms.

Comment: It's not quite as simple. The above transform is a rotation about the origin.

Comment: So is the diagram in the question: the origin is at the lower left corner.